# No route matches {:locale=>:en, :action=>"email", :controller=>"games"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

As I have written in the title I get the following error when I try to click on my games page.

This is what I have in my games_controller:

```
   def email

    respond_to do |format|
       user = @game.user
       email = user.email
       g = GameTrade.game_interest(user)
       g.deliver
       format.html { redirect_to root_url }
       format.json { render json: @game }
    end
   end
```

and this is what I have in the show.html.erb

```
 <%= button_to "Send Email", :action => 'email'%>
```

in my routes page I do have the line resources :games

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"email" is not a standard route for a resource, so you'll need to add a route for it. Ideally this would be a POST request, since following that link (button) causes changes to occur. Finally, you should really stick to using the url helpers rather than specifying actions as they make your code a little brittle.

Try something like this in your routes.rb:

```
resources :games do
  post 'email', :on => :member
end
```

Then in your view, generate your button like so:

```
<%= button_to "Send Email", email_game_path(@game) %>
```

You'll then need to find the game in your email action in the usual way before you can do anything with it:

```
@game = Game.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: ah that's great Jon, I actually already had the last line in my controller it just didn't copy over here :s Out of curiosity what is the :member in the routes for future reference?

Comment: Member tells the route that you're expecting a resource ID for game. Otherwise it would be a :collection, just the same as the index action. Other member actions are show, edit, create, update, destroy. They all expect a resource ID.